# Delphi XE6 32bit compilation timestamp is not exact

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Do you know why the compilation timestamp in the output exe file is exactly two hours behind the system clock?

Comment: Daylight saving time? but i have not idea if there are different locale settings between applications

Comment: Are you talking about the TimeDateStamp in the COFF header?

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp is recorded in UTC. You are presumably in a timezone that is two hours ahead of UTC.